# python - How to avoid closing the teminal

Tags: python

A real noob question.

I just wrote my first *Hello World !* python program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():
    print ('Hello World !')
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately, when I launch it, it opens the terminal for a fraction of a second. How to avoid that it exits straight.

I look for something like `pause` in Windows command line.

Comment: No offense but a very fast search on google gave me this, took me 8 seconds - `raw_input('Press Enter to exit')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several solutions:

- Launch a command line and then run your Python program in it, with `python <your_file>`, it'll not exit the console ;
- With a good IDE, you can put a breakpoint at the end of your main ([example with Pydev](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html)) ;
- Ask a fake user input, which will freeze the program, waiting for the input

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
       input("Press <Enter> to exit.")      # Python 3, raw_input if Py2
  ```

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct and complete answer. I tried Geany as IDE, and yes, it allows to run the program in a console that doesn't close right away.

Comment: It should be "Press enter to exit."

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Indeed, corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Wait for a keystroke:

```
raw_input("Press <Enter> to exit.")
```

This will prompt the user for input and wait until it is received, at which point, the program will exit

Comment: If there's an error, it may not reach this point and the window will still disappear

Comment: @mhlester Then i highly suggest OP has Exception checks in place - https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: And what if it happens to be a syntax error?